# SQL INSERT INTO with SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert column `NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,STATUSOUT` from table `DAILYDATAWH` into table `SUMMARYDATA` with WHERE condition and this is my query :

```
INSERT INTO SUMMARYDATA(NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT)
SELECT  NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN = MIN(d.STATUSIN), STATUSOUT = MAX(d.STATUSOUT)
FROM DAILYDATAWH d
WHERE LEFT(STATUSIN,13)=LEFT(STATUSOUT,13)
GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT
```

And it's actually work. But, i wanna use WHERE Condition without GROUP BY, is it Possible? Because there is data that's have `NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT` same with others. How to solve the problem?

> This is query for sample data, to insert value into table `DAILYDATAWH`

```
INSERT INTO DAILYDATAWH (NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT) 
VALUES 
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/21/2020 8:00:00 AM', '1/21/2020 8:06:22 AM'),
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/21/2020  8:16:07 AM', '1/21/2020  9:51:21 AM'),
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/21/2020 10:00:00 AM', '1/21/2020 10:06:22 AM'),
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/21/2020  11:16:07 AM', '1/21/2020  12:51:21 AM'),
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/22/2020 8:05:00 AM', '1/22/2020 8:15:22 AM'),
    ('A1', 'ARIA', 'BB', '1/22/2020  9:20:07 AM', '1/22/2020  10:00:21 AM');
```

For the following sample data in table `DAILYDATAWH` this is the sample output that i want in table `SUMMARYDATA`

[image: Output]

Comment: Show us some sample DAILYDATAWH data, and what you want to INSERT into the other table. [mcve]

Comment: if you don't use "GROUP BY" then you can't use MIN and MAX aggregations. On the other hand, without using "GROUP BY", MIN and MAX, you will insert duplicates in the table (if the key is made by the 3 fields NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT), which may or may not be wrong.

Comment: Please check my updated question @jarlh

Comment: With that table data, what's expected to be inserted into SUMMARYDATA?

Comment: @Dea Ananda if you give sample data and expected output, it will

Comment: I use MIN and MAX aggregations because i just want to select minimum datetime in column `STATUSIN` and maximum datetime in column `STATUSOUT` @GiovanniLuisotto

Comment: @DeaAnanda just don't use `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions if you don't want them. If you want the aggregates, you either need `GROUP BY`, or the `OVER` clause. With that test data though, you'll end up with 6 identical rows

Comment: and I use WHERE condition because i just want select same date when `STATUSIN` and `STATUSOUT` in same row @GiovanniLuisotto

Comment: IN that case you have a serious problem - strings aren't dates. Using string manipulations and comparison fails in one way or another. Use proper `datetime2` fields instead, and compare the dates with eg `cast(statusin as date)=cast(statusout as date)`. SQL Server's optimizer is smart enough to convert this into a range query that can use indexes *BUT* it won't be able to calculate statistics accurately.  Better yet, add `date` fields to hold the dates and compare those. You could use a persisted computed column for this

Comment: please check my updated question, there is sample data and an expected output @JonWay

Comment: Can you show me the query to solve this? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: Get your SELECT statement correct first testing with a tool that will allow you to see that only a single record set is being returned then once this is correct, drop it into the INSERT, surround the query with brackets to parenthesize.

Comment: If it is working, why do you need to change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function :

```
INSERT INTO SUMMARYDATA(NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT)
     SELECT DISTINCT d.NIP, d.NAME, d.DEPARTMENT,
            MIN(d.STATUSIN) OVER (PARTITION BY d.NIP, d.NAME, d.DEPARTMENT, convert(date, d.STATUSIN)) as STATUSIN,
            MAX(d.STATUSOUT) OVER (PARTITION BY d.NIP, d.NAME, d.DEPARTMENT, convert(date, d.STATUSOUT)) as STATUSOUT
     FROM DAILYDATAWH d;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me, it's work:) but how to insert that value into table `SUMMARYDATA`?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired result, which is the Min STATUSIN and Max STATUSOUT by NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT the best and simplest way (to me) is to use GROUP BY, it will be done anyway even if you use a windowing function

```
INSERT INTO SUMMARYDATA(NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, STATUSIN, STATUSOUT)
SELECT  NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, MIN(STATUSIN), MAX(STATUSOUT)
FROM DAILYDATAWH d
WHERE CAST(STATUSIN as date) = CAST(STATUSOUT AS date)
GROUP BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT
```

As suggested in the comments cast your strings to actual dates in order to avoid problems, as the one explained below

```
--in your original query you use
{...} WHERE LEFT(STATUSIN,13) = {...}
-- which i.e. translates to
SELECT LEFT ('1/21/2020 8:00:00 AM',13)
which result is '1/21/2020 8:0', so it actually compares date, hour and part of the minutes
-- another example
SELECT LEFT ('1/21/2020 10:00:00 AM',13) 
results in '1/21/2020 10:', so this case compares only date and hour
```

As you can see this is something you want to avoid

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but i I use MIN and MAX aggregations because i just want to select minimum datetime in column `STATUSIN` and maximum datetime in column `STATUSOUT`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using ranking functions.

```
;WITH CTE_Status AS
(SELECT  NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, StatusIn, StatusOut ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT,CAST(StatusIn AS Date) ORDER BY d.STATUSIN) AS StatusIn_rnk, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NIP, NAME, DEPARTMENT, CAST(StatusIn AS Date) ORDER BY d.STATUSOUT DESC) AS StatusOut_rnk
FROM DAILYDATAWH d
)
SELECT a.NIP, a.Name, a.Department,a.StatusIn, b.StatusOut 
FROM CTE_Status AS a
JOIN CTE_Status AS b
ON a.StatusIn_rnk = b.StatusOut_rnk
WHERE a.StatusIn_rnk = 1;
```